# How to get results count from each entry ID - PHP/SQL?

Tags: php, sql, count

here is a small sample of what im trying.. as its hardly to code it here I have uploaded an image..

http://i46.tinypic.com/5bxn5u.png

just want to display the total number of reservations for each room.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to join the tables together and use `COUNT()` with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.name, COUNT(*) AS num_reservations
FROM
    availables a
    LEFT JOIN reservations r
        ON r.available_id = a.id
GROUP BY
    a.id
```

This should give you a list of each room with a total number of reservations each has.

To put it into your existing query, you can use the following:

```
$coordinator = (isset($_GET['uidse']) && is_numeric($_GET['uidse'])) ? (int)$_GET['uidse'] : 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS num_reservations FROM availables LEFT JOIN reservations ON availables.id=reservations.available_id WHERE coordinator='" . $coordinator . "' GROUP BY availables.id");
```

I placed `$coordinator` outside of the MySQL query and added very basic validation/sanitization to save you from a SQL-Injection headache in the future.

Comment: I want to get the availables and reserv count for specific coordinator as this is for their dashboard eg. WHERE coordinator=4

Comment: @user1596253 My second query, the one showing how to implement it with *your* code shows how to do that, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT availables.name, COUNT(*) FROM availables
LEFT JOIN reservations ON reservations.available_id = availables.id
GROUP BY reservations.available_id
```

Comment: there should be multiple coordinator,.. how to get an expecifid coordinator.. eg. WHERE coordinator=4